# How to use kpfonts in Beamer main text?

Tags: beamer, fonts

I use kpfonts as main mathfonts in Beamer, and it works well, but the main text font is not kpfonts, my question is how to make the main text fonts using kpfonts?

here is my preamble:

```
\documentclass[UTF8]{beamer}
\usepackage{xeCJK}

\usefonttheme{serif}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts} % using non standard fonts for beamer
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\setCJKmainfont{FZSKBXKJW.TTF}
\begin{document}
...
\end{document}
```

here is a snapshot, you can see the main text font is the default beamer serif font:
[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Is `FZSKBXKJW` a real name of a font or, at least, font file?

Comment: yes, it is a real name of font, FZSKBXKJW.TTF

Comment: And when you add a MWE please specify if you want the sans serif or serif version of the font for text and for math.

Answer (score 1):

`kpfonts` are (amongst others) available as T1 font. With beamer you could use them like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usefonttheme{serif}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{kpfonts}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

a test

$a test$

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]